# How to read data in DSX from Data hub object storage container?

Tags: dataset, data-cleaning

I am creating a new notebook with DSX. I have a data set that I want to use. It is not CSV. I found that I could go to Data hub by clicking top-right tile near my logged in name, then object storage in dropdown and finally upload a text file.

How do I read this file in my notebook? Do I need to create a connection ?

Comment: I recently ran into a similar situation (I guess). I was trying to read a text file in the notebook that I have uploaded to CloudObjectStorage linked to my DSX project. Please check the following question, I am not sure if you are using the same parameters: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/27446/how-to-access-a-text-file-from-ibm-dsx-scala-spark-notebook/27447#27447