# How to Access a Text File from IBM DSX Scala-Spark Notebook

Tags: apache-spark, scala

I have recently faced problem in accessing text files that I have uploaded from my local computer to the IBM DSX Cloud Object Storage so that I can use it in my Spark-Scala notebooks. It appeared to me that the general configuration of the platform is focused on CSV format; so is most of the help material. In fact, I figured a way around when I changed the extension of my .txt file to .csv. Through this post and the answer followed, I am trying to share my experience with others.

This post is useful, if:

- You have created a IBM DSX notebook with “Language=Scala” and “Spark version=2.1 OR 2.0″[did not try with other versions]
- AND You are trying to access a text file [did not try other formats] that you have uploaded from your personal computer to the IBM Cloud Object Storage

Comment: One problem with this question, is that it is not a question.  At Stack Exchange we do Questions and Answers.  It is OK to answer your own question, and is a good way to share information. But the questions need to be a clear question, and the answers need to answer that question.  Please review the How to Ask page referenced in the **put on hold** notice above.

Answer (score 1):

In order to access files that are in Cloud Object Storage, you need to provide the path of the file in the form of a CloudObjectStorage instance. Add following lines, after the file credentials, to your code:

var soc = new CloudObjectStorage(sc, credentials, null, “bluemix_cos”) var myFile = sc.textFile(soc.url(“your_bucket”,”data.txt”))

In the second code line above, “your_bucket” is the value of “BUCKET” in the file credentials.

There is one last thing we need to do before we are good to go. The CloudObjectStorage constructor accepts credentials in a way that is for the CSV files. Luckily the main difference between the two formats is the HashMap key names; hence, we can easily manage this problem by changing the above credentials manually, as mentioned below:

“IBM_API_KEY_ID” as “apiKey”

“IAM_SERVICE_ID” as “serviceId”

“ENDPOINT” as “endPoint”

“IBM_AUTH_ENDPOINT” as “iamServiceEndpoint”

For further details, you can visit the link below:
http://rehmans.org/2018/01/31/how-to-access-a-text-file-from-ibm-dsx-scala-spark-notebook/